# How can I send a variable from the Server-side to the Client-side?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to pass a variable from my Protect Page Load to the Client Side JavaScript but when I try to

```
var variable=<%=count %>
```

It gives me an error which says:"Expected Expression", what can I do in this situation? How can I pass the variable?

my code:

```
<script runat="server">
 public int countSK = 0;
 public int countFaze = 0;
 public int countAstralis = 0;
 public int countNip = 0;
 public int countCloud = 0;
 public int countG2 = 0;
 public int countNorth = 0;
 public int countVP = 0;
 public int countMouz = 0;
 public int countLiquid = 0;
 public int countGambit = 0;
 public int countFnatic = 0;
 public int countRene = 0;
 public int countEnvy = 0;
 public int countNavi = 0;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((string)Session["username"] != "ADMIN")
    {
        Response.Redirect("NotAdmin.aspx");
        Response.End();
    }
    string conStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\KatzirDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    string cmdStr = "SELECT favT FROM tbl";
    SqlConnection conObj = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    SqlCommand cmdObj = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conObj);
    conObj.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmdObj.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string team= dr["favT"].ToString();
            switch (team)
            {
                case "sk": countSK++; break;
                case "faze": countFaze++; break;
                case "astralis": countAstralis++; break;
                case "nip": countNip++; break;
                case "cloud9": countCloud++; break;
                case "g2": countG2++; break;
                case "north": countNorth++; break;
                case "vp": countVP++; break;
                case "mouz": countMouz++; break;
                case "liquid": countLiquid++; break;
                case "gambit": countGambit++; break;
                case "fnatic": countFnatic++; break;
                case "renegades": countRene++; break;
                case "envyus": countEnvy++; break;
                case "navi": countNavi++; break;
            }
        }
    }
    conObj.Close();
}
```

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">




    // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
    // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
    // draws it.
    function drawChart() {
        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
      ['SK',<%=countSK %>],
      ['Faze',<%=countFaze%>],
      ['Astralis',<%=countAstralis%>],
       ['Nip',<%=countNip %>],
      ['Cloud9',<%=countCloud%>],
      ['G2',<%=countG2%>]
       ['North',<%=countNorth %>],
      ['VP',<%=countVP%>],
      ['Mouz',<%=countMouz%>]
       ['Liquid',<%=countLiquid %>],
      ['Gambit',<%=countGambit%>],
      ['Fnatic',<%=countFnatic%>]
       ['Renegades',<%=countRene %>],
      ['EnvyUs',<%=countEnvy%>],
      ['Navi',<%=countNavi%>]
    ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = { 'title': 'Favorite Team',
            'width': 400,
            'height': 300
        };
        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

Here you go I added my code if you can find my problem I would really much appreciate it thanks!!

Comment: Have you declared your server side variable as public ?

Comment: Please post your code-behind with the page load and the declaration of the variable

Comment: Tried Doing so @Prany and it didn't work either.

Comment: You are likely missing single quotes: `var variable = '<%=count%>'`; and then `count` should be defined as a public property on the page.

Comment: use single quotes as well var variable='<%=count %>'

Comment: Ok I put it in single quotes and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please use below and Make sure you declare your variable at the top of the class as Public

```
var variable='<%=count %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely missing single quotes: `var variable = '<%=count%>';` and then count should be defined as a **public property** on the page